# Fields not showing in design view

Tags: ms-access, field, ms-access-2003, corruption

I'm working on an Access 2003 database, divided into front and back ends. I've attempted to compact and repair the database, which appears to do nothing.

After running various export processes I noticed that some of the columns reported as transferred didn't seem to tally with what was displayed in the design view.

```vba
Public Sub Test()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim f As field
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs("TBL tablename")

    For Each f In td.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Name
        Debug.Print f.Properties("ColumnHidden").value
    Next f

    Set f = Nothing
    Set td = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Further tests ascertained that the table actually had several fields, some of which were replication fields (the database had previously been replicated, but not anymore).  More importantly, some of the fields were required data fields, containing data necessary to the project.

I have some questions regarding this:

- Is there a setting in the background that allows the field to be hidden ***in design view***?
- If not, is this a good indicator of corruption?

### Update

I've tested the theory further by writing a query to pull the data back, which also works fine:

[image: Query Design Grid]

[image: Results]

...and the table design...

[image: Table design]

### Update *(06/06/2016)*

I've written a process to extract as much data as possible from the database and drop it into a new one. Though I don't think Microsoft Access is a suitable platform for this application, at present it will have to suffice. In the future, I will attempt to move it to SQL Server to stablise its operation, but in the meantime it will have to serve as is.

I've posted the solution I used to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327152/indexing-in-vba-access-2003-field-association).

Comment: @HansUp: This is purely a data store; there are no modules, forms or reports to cause any compilation issues.

Comment: If the problem remains, import one of the problem tables into a new Access database, tell us the name of a field which exists in that table but is not displayed in Design View, upload that database to a file sharing site and give us a link.

Comment: @HansUp: Thanks, HansUp.  I'm going about this another way; I'm going to recreate all of the tables into the same database using VBA and import these copies into a new database. There are fields present and missing that I want to ensure are there. There are multiple issues with the database, so I'm having to use various fixes here and there.

Comment: @HansUp: Also, I did import the table into another database, as suggested, and the field was returned. I also attempted an XML export of the database, which solved other problems, such as certain tables that were missing, but not the missing field issues! Crazier than a box of frogs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to accept the fact that this database is corrupt.  There were too many issues boiling up, including:

- Missing fields in tables
- Tables not copying to other databases
- Inability to compact and repair the database (the C&R would return instantly without doing anything)
- Inability to remove the replication applied to the database