# Indexing in VBA (Access 2003) - field association

Tags: ms-access, indexing, vba, field

Based on [this tutorial page](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=176:microsoft-access-dao-object-model-create-an-index-create-relationship-between-fields-create-and-exceute-a-query&catid=79&Itemid=475), how does Microsoft Access know that a field created for an index fields collection associates to an equivalent field in the TableDef fields collection?

Even in [this Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/217011), fields are *created* for the index and then appended to the index's fields collection:

```vb
...
'Copy Indexes
For I1 = 0 To SourceTableDef.Indexes.Count - 1
  Set SI = SourceTableDef.Indexes(I1)
  If Not SI.Foreign Then         ' Foreign indexes are added by relationships
    Set I = T.CreateIndex()
    ' Copy Jet Properties
      On Error Resume Next
      For P1 = 0 To I.Properties.Count - 1
        I.Properties(P1).Value = SI.Properties(P1).Value
      Next P1
      On Error GoTo 0
    ' Copy Fields
      For f1 = 0 To SI.Fields.Count - 1
        Set F = T.CreateField(SI.Fields(f1).Name, T.Fields(SI.Fields(f1).Name).Type)
        I.Fields.Append F
      Next f1
    T.Indexes.Append I
  End If
Next I1
...
```

Can't I simply add the existing field from the TableDef's fields collection?  This makes little sense and seems to have very little in the way of cohesion.

### Update

I actually tested the code [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/217011) which is basically what I want to do ... but it fails with an undefined object error on this line:

```vb
Set F = T.CreateField(SI.Fields(f1).Name, T.Fields(SI.Fields(f1).Name).Type)
```

...and we have all sorts of fun when we change this.

*(23/05/2016)* Further, this script appears to be wrong - the second argument shouldn't actually be there, it's unnecessary. Omitting it causes further errors! Ha! Where's my tail? I'm getting the feeling that I should be chasing it.

### A solution to my problem

I decided to follow HansUp's lead and use DDL - far easier than attempting to trawl through the problems associated to the manipulation of objects (though there was some level of this in the final code design)...

```vb
Option Compare Database

Public Const cFname As String = "drm\drmData2016.accdb"
Public Const cPropNotFound As Integer = 3270
Public Const cNotSupported As Integer = 3251
Public Const cInvalidOp As Integer = 3219

Public Sub GenerateTables()
    
    OpenLog
    
    'Initalise...
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tdb As Database
    
    Dim ts As TableDef, tt As TableDef
    Dim p As Property
    Dim f As Field, ft As Field
    Dim i As Index
    Dim s As String, t As String
    Dim x As Boolean
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    If Dir$(cFname) <> "" Then Kill cFname
    Set tdb = Application.DBEngine.CreateDatabase(cFname, dbLangGeneral, dbVersion140)
    WriteLog "Created database " & cFname & "."
    
    'Create the tables...
    WriteLog "Creating TableDefs...", 1
    For Each ts In db.TableDefs
        If Not StartsWith(ts.Name, "msys", "~", "$", "Name AutoCorrect") And Not EndsWith(ts.Name, "_xrep") Then
            s = "SELECT "
            For Each f In ts.Fields
                If Not StartsWith(f.Name, "s_", "S_") Then s = s & "[" & f.Name & "], "
            Next f
            s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 2) & " INTO [" & ts.Name & "] IN """ & cFname & """ FROM [" & ts.Name & "];"
            On Error Resume Next
                db.Execute s
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    WriteLog "Created [" & ts.Name & "] using " & s, 2
                Else
                    WriteLog "Failed to create [" & ts.Name & "].", 2
                    WriteLog "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, 3
                    WriteLog "SQL: " & s, 3
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                tdb.TableDefs.Refresh
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next ts
    
    'Copy the properties...
    WriteLog "Tables...", 1
    For Each ts In db.TableDefs
        
        If Not StartsWith(ts.Name, "msys", "~", "$", "Name Autocorrect") And Not EndsWith(ts.Name, "_xrep") Then
            
            Set tt = tdb.TableDefs(ts.Name)
            
            WriteLog ts.Name, 2
            
            WriteLog "Table Properties...", 3
            'Table properties...
            For Each p In ts.Properties
                On Error Resume Next
                    tt.Properties(p.Name) = p.value
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then
                        WriteLog p.Name & " = " & p.value, 3
                    Else
                        WriteLog "Error setting " & p.Name, 3
                        WriteLog Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, 4
                        Err.Clear
                    End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next p
            
            'Field properties...
            WriteLog "Fields...", 3
            For Each f In ts.Fields
                If Not StartsWith(f.Name, "s_") Then
                    Set ft = tt.Fields(f.Name)
                    WriteLog f.Name, 3
                    WriteLog "Properties...", 3
                    For Each p In f.Properties
                        On Error Resume Next
                            ft.Properties(p.Name).value = p.value
                            Select Case Err.Number
                                Case 0
                                    'Normal...
                                    WriteLog p.Name & " = " & p.value, 4
                                Case cPropNotFound
                                    'Create the property...
                                    Dim np As Property
                                    Set np = ft.CreateProperty(p.Name, p.Type, p.value)
                                    ft.Properties.Append np
                                    ft.Properties.Refresh
                                    WriteLog "Created property " & p.Name & ", value of " & p.value, 4
                                Case cNotSupported, cInvalidOp
                                    'We're not worried about these values - simply skip over them...
                                Case Else
                                    WriteLog "Failed to create or change property " & p.Name & ".", 4
                                    WriteLog "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, 5
                                    Err.Clear
                            End Select
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Next p
                End If
            Next f
            
            'Create the indexes...
            WriteLog "Table indexes...", 2
            For Each i In ts.Indexes
                x = False
                s = "CREATE "
                If i.Unique Then s = s & "UNIQUE "
                s = s & "INDEX [" & i.Name & "] ON [" & ts.Name & "] ("
                For Each f In i.Fields
                    s = s & "[" & f.Name & "], "
                    'Just make sure we're not dealing with replication fields...
                    x = StartsWith(f.Name, "s_")
                Next f
                'We only want
                If Not x Then
                    WriteLog i.Name, 3
                    s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 2) & ") "
                    If i.Primary Or i.IgnoreNulls Or i.Required Then
                        s = s & "WITH "
                        If i.Primary Then s = s & "PRIMARY "
                        If i.IgnoreNulls Then s = s & "IGNORE NULL "
                        If i.Required Then s = s & "DISALLOW NULL "
                    End If
                    s = s & ";"
                    On Error Resume Next
                        tdb.Execute s
                        Select Case Err.Number
                            'Note: used select case just in case I need to add extra error numbers...
                            Case 0
                                'Normal...
                                WriteLog "Created index [" & i.Name & "] using " & s, 4
                            Case Else
                                WriteLog "Failed to create index [" & ts.Name & "].", 4
                                WriteLog "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, 5
                                WriteLog "SQL: " & s, 3
                                Err.Clear
                        End Select
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            Next i
            
        End If
        
    Next ts
    
    'Belt and braces tidy-up...
    Set p = Nothing
    Set f = Nothing
    Set ft = Nothing
    Set i = Nothing
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set tt = Nothing

    tdb.Close
    Set tdb = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    WriteLog "Closed database."
    
    WriteLog "Finished.", , False
    CloseLog
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently my memory was hazy. But the key is that the created field isn't appended to the tabledef (where it exists already) but to the new index. The index is basically a data structure with a collection of field names + types, not pointers to fields. Actually it might work as well to append an existing field, I never tried it.

Comment: @Andre: Thanks for your pointers. I understand that the fields aren't duplicated to the TableDef and vice versa. I did try adding the existing fields from the TableDef (I would have thought that pretty logical), but that errored (duplicate object or something). This is typical Access - very woolly in the way it performs certain actions.

Comment: If you look at "Applies to" of that page, with Access 97 being the highest version - that's ancient. I'd rather use Allen Browne's page as reference.

Comment: Seems much simpler to me to use a [CREATE INDEX Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823109.aspx).

Comment: @HansUp: I was looking for a straightforward method of just programmatically creating the tables, fields and indexes and copying all the properties etc.

Comment: I'll post the overall solution I've used once I manage to get everything to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does Microsoft Access know that a field created for an index
>   fields collection associates to an equivalent field in the TableDef
>   fields collection?

It checks based on the name.  The name of the new index field must exist in the `TableDef` and that field's datatype must be one which is indexable.  If either of those conditions is not satisfied, you will get an error message.

Comment: That's really what I suspected, I just wanted someone who knows more about Access than I do to confirm it. In that case, does the TableDef need to exist before the index is created (i.e. committed to the TableDefs collection) or can it exist in potentia (i.e. as a programmatic object) until committed, while the index is being generated?

Comment: ...and that's probably where the issues with the code lies, in that case. All of the examples I've seen, so far, are appending the indexes to the TableDef *before* the TableDef is actually part of the TableDef collection. That could be why it's failing. I'll try that. Many thanks, HansUp.

Comment: Strangely, though, the process will allow me to add the index object to the indexes collection prior to the commit of the TableDef itself. VBA errors once I then try to append the table to the TableDefs collection.

Comment: Ah!  Sorry I didn't realize the index field verification could be deferred until the `TableDef` is appended.  I withdrew my misguided comment.  I rarely use those DAO methods since I find DDL so much simpler.

Comment: *I rarely use those DAO methods since I find DDL so much simpler.* - I wish!

Comment: So, based on DDL, is there anyway of writing other properties into the creation of a table using DDL, such as adding an input mask or format to the column, or does this need to be handled using VBA, purely (i.e. set the properties of the newly DDL created table)?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX` is the DDL I was talking about.  Properties such as input mask and column format don't apply to an index.  If you want to talk about table creation, I still start with DDL and do everything DDL supports.  Anything else ... validation rule, description, input mask, etc. ... I do with DAO methods on the newly-created `TableDef`.

Comment: That's fine. Many thanks, that's what I expected, really, but I was attempting to be optimistic!  ;o)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, @HansUp.

Answer (score 1):

In summary:
An index is (from DAO point of view) basically a data structure with some properties and a collection of field names + their data types.

It is *not* a collection of pointers to tabledef fields.

To add fields to an index via DAO one needs a field object, which is created by `CreateField()`.

The index object has a `.CreateField()` method too, which is actually the more common way to do this, I'd say.

From http://allenbrowne.com/func-dao.html#CreateIndexesDAO :

```vb
'3. Multi-field index.
Set ind = tdf.CreateIndex("FullName")
With ind
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("Surname")
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("FirstName")
End With
tdf.Indexes.Append ind
```

Note that [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837208%28v=office.15%29.aspx) doesn't take the `Type` and `Size` parameters, only the `Name`. I will happily admit that all this is a bit confusing (or incoherent, if you want).

Comment: Bearing this in mind, that would make the two pages by Microsoft, themselves, wrong!  Now there's a surprise. Thanks, Andre, I'll attempt this and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, @Andre.